# How is this app converting from an IOConnection/IO to a future when integrating with Play?

Tags: scala, playframework, scala-cats, doobie

I'm looking at this repo on github that is using both play and doobie.

I want to understand how it is eventually converting from a connectionIO/IO from cats to a Future that the playframework is built around from.

I'm looking at a controller and I can see the userRepo but I don't see where or how it is going to/from futures to IO.

```
  def doEdit(): Action[AnyContent] = UserAction { implicit req =>
    GsForms.user.bindFromRequest.fold(
      formWithErrors => editView(formWithErrors),
      data => userRepo.edit(data)
        .map(_ => Redirect(PublishedSpeakerRoutes.detail(req.user.slug)).flashing("success" -> "Profile updated"))
    )
```

}

https://github.com/gospeak-io/gospeak/blob/36fd9dd4ebe314c2ca8e02e2e2c714b6d399d045/web/app/gospeak/web/pages/user/profile/ProfileCtrl.scala#L28

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventually there is a call to [`unsafeToFuture`](https://typelevel.org/cats-effect/datatypes/io.html#unsafetofuture) which

> Evaluates the effect and produces the result in a Future.

at line [UICtrl.scala#L59](https://github.com/gospeak-io/gospeak/blob/36fd9dd4ebe314c2ca8e02e2e2c714b6d399d045/web/app/gospeak/web/utils/UICtrl.scala#L59). These questions are best answered by [Goto definition](https://scalameta.org/metals/blog/2018/12/12/fast-goto-definition.html) feature of IDE. For example, Metals provides it for all major [editors](https://scalameta.org/metals/docs/editors/overview.html#editor-support). Often the shortcut is `command+click` or `control+click` on the symbol name.

[image]

Comment: oh I see, so everything can be cats "friendly" until the last moment when you need to return Play's action results.  So they just created custom Action results which perform the  conversion there, got it!